# Pass the request of Mule ESB service to conditional routers

Tags: esb, mule

I am exposing a CXF service using Mule ESB and i need to pass on the request as is to the Conditional routers. Most of the examples I see pass the response to conditional routers.

How do I pass the request forward without changing the wsdl?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're looking for: do you have any bit of configuration you could share? That'll help helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a web-service-proxy pattern provided by Mule ESB 3

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="theProxy" 
         outboundAddress="vm://theProxyFlow" 
        wsdlFile="classpath:wsdl/MyWsWSDL.wsdl" inboundAddress="${inbound.url}" transformer-refs="RequestToString">
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

And the VM endpoint actually does the Condition based routing by using xpath expression. However I had to write a "RequestToString" custom transformer so that I could apply xpath on the incoming SOAP payload.

I used the following transformation in the transformer -

```
      if (src instanceof InputStream)
        {
            InputStream input = (InputStream) src;
            try
            {
                reqAsString = IOUtils.toString(input);
            }
            finally
            {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

*I'll revise this answer when the OP will have given more precision*

Place a [choice routing message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice) after the component that implements your web service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For completeness purposes I have documented what I ended up doing in my answer(do let me know if there is a better way to do it).

Comment: Cool. You should be able to use a standard object-to-string-transformer in lieu of your custom RequestToString. Otherwise, that's pretty well done :)